# Opening system files in Python for hashing Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, permissions, checksum

I am trying to get my program to go through the C:\Windows directory recursively, and taking many details including the md5 checksum of the files. It works great, except for the fact that it can't get permission to take the checksum of the files. This function gets called from my main function, with the variable `filename` being the full path to the file that is trying to be hashed. The error occurs on the line with `f = open(filename,'rb')` with the error:

```
---> 84     f = open(filename,'rb')
 85     for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128*md5.block_size),b''):
 86         md5.update(chunk)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET'
```

Here's the function:

```
def checksum_md5(filename):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128*md5.block_size),b''):
        md5.update(chunk)
        return md5.hexdigest()
```

The program isn't changing the files, it just needs to read them and get the checksum. How can I get this to work? It works up until the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET directory, and works as expected.

Thanks a ton!

-Golfer

Comment: Make sure that you as the user have full access to this folder. (Read and write permissions) Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I tried to give myself full permissions in all of the C:\Windows\* directory using both takeown and icacls, and it still gives me the same cannot access. I tried two different things, once giving my specific user permissions and the other giving the admin group permissions.

Comment: Is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` a file, or is it a directory?

Comment: @duskwuff From experience that would **most likely** be a directory.

Comment: Directory. I just realized my problem. I have a function that makes sure the input is a file not a directory, by checking if it has a '.' in the name. How can I make it do this differently now to fix this? `def isfile(name):
    if '.' in name:
        return True
    else:
        return False` is the code. Thanks.

Comment: @1998golfer You say you used takeown and icacls. Have you simply tried Right Clicking > Properties > Permissions and editing it in there?

Comment: @FinnRayment it tells me that I don't have permission to change the permissions. I am admin. It's because they're system files. But I think that's not my problem anymore.

Comment: @1998golfer Well, check the new answer you got. Maybe that will help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted in the comments, the object that you're trying to open is a directory, not a file. Windows doesn't permit you to open and read from directories like that.*

To determine if an object is a directory, use the `os.path.isdir()` function. It'll return `True` if the path you pass to it is a directory. `os.path` also has an `isfile()` function, which does the same thing, except checking if a path is a normal file.

---

*: It *is* possible to open and read from directories on some operating systems (sometimes with a special flag to `open()`, but that's not what you want to do here anyways.

Comment: Thank you a million. I tried with only executing if not os.path.isdir(name) == True, but it still let C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET slip through into it. I tried with using isfile() instead, and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @1998golfer Consider checking this as the correct answer. You both get rep. xD

Comment: Okay, did that. python is now creating a sqlite database containing the filename, full path, and md5sum of all the files in C:\Windows. This may be a while.

Comment: @duskwuff, it ran for a while, but then just stopped with a similar error as earlier. In the directory `C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6`, it tries to take the hash of the file 'pq' which is just a file with no file extension. Anything I can do to modify my code to fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: The CSC folder is special — [it's used for offline file caching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/27/54712.aspx). It's probably best to skip it.

Comment: Okay. I made a few changes: 1 to account for IOError exceptions (tells me about them but doesn't end script), and makes it only check .exe, .dll, and .msc files. With all files it would be going through ~115,000 files at a rate of about 100 per 10-15 seconds. No thanks. Just with those files got it down to 28,800 candidates.